# Create vector of same size in R or awk

Tags: r, awk

I have a file with 3 columns as shown below:

```
ID  DIST    DIST1
ID1 0,0,142 0,0,7,1
ID2 0,0,142 0,2,5
ID3 0,0,141,1   0,0,8
ID4 0,0,141,1   0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
ID5 0,0,108,32,2    0,0,7,1
```

The number of elements in column2 and column3 differ in few rows. I would need to have same number of elements in column2 and column3 by adding '0' .

For instance, in the first row, column2 has 3 elements and column3 has 4 elements. So in the output, '0' is added to column2 to have equal number of elements in both column2 and column3.

Similary in the 3rd row, column2 has 4 elements and column3 has 3 elements. And in the output '0' is added to column3 to have 4 elements.

The sample output looks like below:

```
ID  DIST    DIST1
ID1 0,0,142,0   0,0,7,1
ID2 0,0,142 0,2,5
ID3 0,0,141,1   0,0,8,0
ID4 0,0,141,1,0,0,0,0   0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
ID5 0,0,108,32,2    0,0,7,1,0
```

Is there any soultion in R to do this for every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly vectorized (R) possibility. I'm assuming you have character vectors (rather factors) and utilizing several `stringi` package functions in order to count the commas (though you can do this in base R too) and duplicate `",0"`, (it is not possible to use the `pad` functions to pad longer than 1 vectors)

```
### Your data as I see it
df <- read.table(text = "ID  DIST    DIST1
                 ID1 0,0,142 0,0,7,1
                 ID2 0,0,142 0,2,5
                 ID3 0,0,141,1   0,0,8
                 ID4 0,0,141,1   0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
                 ID5 0,0,108,32,2    0,0,7,1", 
                 header = TRUE, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ## not factors

library(stringi)
res <- sapply(df[-1], stri_count_fixed, ",") ## Count commas in order asses string length
indx <- cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(-res) + 1) ## Find the shorter strings
df[indx] <- paste0(df[indx], stri_dup(",0", abs(res[, 1] - res[, 2]))) ## Pad ",0"s 
df
#    ID              DIST           DIST1
# 1 ID1         0,0,142,0         0,0,7,1
# 2 ID2           0,0,142           0,2,5
# 3 ID3         0,0,141,1         0,0,8,0
# 4 ID4 0,0,141,1,0,0,0,0 0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
# 5 ID5      0,0,108,32,2       0,0,7,1,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I can propose using base R and a `for` loop. The `f` function does the trick in order to make the two vectors of different length to have equal length:

```
f <- function(v1, v2) {a <- rbind(v1, v2=v2[seq(v1)])[2,]; a[is.na(a)] <- 0; return(a);}

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    v1 <- strsplit(df[i,]$DIST, ",")[[1]]
    v2 <- strsplit(df[i,]$DIST1, ",")[[1]]
    if (length(v1)>length(v2))
        df[i,]$DIST1 <- paste0(f(v1, v2), collapse=",")
    else
        df[i,]$DIST <- paste0(f(v2,v1), collapse=",")
}

   # ID              DIST           DIST1
# 1 ID1         0,0,142,0         0,0,7,1
# 2 ID2           0,0,142           0,2,5
# 3 ID3         0,0,141,1         0,0,8,0
# 4 ID4 0,0,141,1,0,0,0,0 0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
# 5 ID5      0,0,108,32,2       0,0,7,1,0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), DIST = c("0,0,142", 
"0,0,142", "0,0,141,1", "0,0,141,1", "0,0,108,32,2"), DIST1 = c("0,0,7,1", 
"0,2,5", "0,0,8", "0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2", "0,0,7,1")), .Names = c("ID", 
"DIST", "DIST1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    m = gsub(/,/,"&",$2)
    n = gsub(/,/,"&",$3)
    for (i=m; i<n; i++) {
        $2 = $2 ",0"
    }
    for (i=n; i<m; i++) {
        $3 = $3 ",0"
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID  DIST    DIST1
ID1 0,0,142,0 0,0,7,1
ID2 0,0,142 0,2,5
ID3 0,0,141,1 0,0,8,0
ID4 0,0,141,1,0,0,0,0 0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
ID5 0,0,108,32,2 0,0,7,1,0

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
ID   DIST               DIST1
ID1  0,0,142,0          0,0,7,1
ID2  0,0,142            0,2,5
ID3  0,0,141,1          0,0,8,0
ID4  0,0,141,1,0,0,0,0  0,0,5,0,0,1,0,2
ID5  0,0,108,32,2       0,0,7,1,0
```